# How to find $\int_{0}^{t}{(g(\tau)\sin(\omega_{0}t - \tau))d\tau}$ for an arbitrary $g(\tau)$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find $\int_{0}^{t}{(g(\tau)\sin(\omega_{0}t - \tau))d\tau}$ for an arbitrary $g(\tau)$, resulting from using a convolution method to solve the differential equation.

I usually deal with complicated integrals involving sin or cos functions by using an integration by parts, but here it does not work, because the second integral of $g(\tau)$ is not necessarily equal to $g(\tau)$. It seems integration by substitution is not possible here as well.

Comment: I think there is no closed form.

Comment: One could write this in terms of the Fourier Transform of $g$.

Comment: What do you mean "find"? There is no closed form for arbitrary $g(t)$ unless you accept some transforms and its inverts (like Fourier transform)